# Where do I save NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have seen countless examples on saving ints using NSUserDefaults but none of them show where I save and load them to.

Where do I put the code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:9001 forKey:@"HighScore"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

in?
Do I put it in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: It depends. I will save it as soon as possible in case user may kill my app and load it just before using it.

Comment: You need to provide more details about what you have tried and what issue you are having. Update your question with specific details and code so we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Be clear in your question. It depends on what you want to do and how you want to do. Generally, saving should take place right where your data to save is available.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your app's requirement. There may be multiple scenarios,

1. You are saving a data into `NSUserDefaults` repeatedly You might want to hold on to saving the data for a little while longer, because if saving to `NSUserDefaults` is taking place repeatedly, you need to decide the best time to save the data to `NSUserDefaults`.

> For example:
>       You are storing user's online/offline status, and checking repeatedly at 1 second, and saving to `NSUserDefaults`, this is very
>   costly process, even in terms of performance and battery consumption.
>   So, you might want to hold on to the saving part, just yet, save your
>   data into `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication
>   *)application` or some other appropriate appDelegate method. This way your data will be saved correctly and without so much battery
>   consumption and affecting performance too.

2. You are saving a huge list to `NSUserDefaults` (which you should not) Well,
   this case is tricky, all devs will say that you should not save huge amount of data to the `NSUserDefaults`, use something else as database, not `NSUserDefaults`. But, if you are still not convinced, You should use `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]`, right after you have access to the data, or right after `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"OBJECT" forKey:@"KEY"]`

> In my opinion, the best place to save any `NSUserDefaults` data is `-
>   (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`. To
>   understand see this example,
>
> You are saving to `NSUserDefaults` 5 times in your app, and let's
>   assume it takes up 0.0001 seconds to execute and takes 0.0001% battery
>   consumption. Total, it will take 0.0001*5=0.0005 seconds to execute
>   and 0.0001*5=0.0005% of your battery.
>
> But, if you do this only once, it would take only 0.0001-0.0002
>   seconds (just assumption) to execute and 0.0001%-0.0002% battery
>   consumption.

Comment: Awesome. I'll do that. Though where do I load my 'high score' int? Do I have it in my viewDidLoad { self.highscoreint = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"]; }   ???

Comment: If you want your highScore to be available at the scope of the class, you should do it in viewDidLoad, else you can fetch right from `NSUserDefaults` whenever you need, literally whenever. For example, you need highScore in only a method called, `calculateFinalScore`, so just fetch it in this method only, then no need to have it declared as property. Else you want to use highScore at multiple locations in the same class, create a property and assign it from `NSUserDefaults` value in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Okay so here is everything is my app so far, and please tell me if I sound confusing....I have 5 View Controller classes in my app including 2 Failure Page and 4 levels. I pass the self.highScoreInt to the next class (next level) if the user beats it. When the user fails they are brought to the Failure Page. In the failurePage.m, the viewDidLoad has {     self.highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.highScoreInt];
} to display the user's high score. Where do I put the NSUserDefaults so that when the label read the loaded 'self.highScoreInt' ? Thank you so much for helping

Comment: Just right before your `self.highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.highScoreInt];`

Comment: Like so? : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:self.highScoreInt forKey:@"HighScore"];

self.highScoreInt = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"];

Comment: Wait, if you are asking me where to save the variable in user defaults, that should be the class from where you are trying to pass the highScore.

Answer (score 0):

You could save your variable and read it from NSUserDefaults anywhere you need. you could save it in AppDelegate, or in ViewDidAppear, whatever you like.

Remember, NSUserDefault is like a local cache for you to save some variable, so when user killed your app or re-launch it from background, you could read some data from it, and knowing the application state where it got paused or stopped.

However, do not abuse using it. It should only save some lightweight data, e.g. last refresh time, username, access token, etc.

Comment: So do I save the int in viewDidLoad and load it in viewDidAppear? @Wingzero

Comment: You must know your logic first. As I said, you could save it anywhere and read it later anywhere. You don't do this in viewDidLoad and read it in viewDidAppear, it does not make sense. NSUserDefault is kind of disk cache, not memory cache. Your application can be deallocated, and all memory cache is gone. however, the next time you relaunch your application , disk cache can still work, and you can get some data as well